# Sun Studio 12 C compiler for Linux is so slow

Tags: c, compiler-construction, sunstudio

I download and tried it today.

It compiles my project but "suncc" is even slower then "gcc" which is famous for its    leisureliness. I just -xO1 which i thought should do no optimizations. I have a lot of inline declared C functions. Is there a way to disable the inlining or anything else to make it compile faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-xO1 does basic optimizations.  According to the [Sun documentation](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/documentation/ss12u1/mr/man/man1/cc.1.html):

```
 On x86 platforms:

      -xO1 Preloads arguments from memory, cross-jumping
           (tail-merging), as well as the single pass of the
           default optimization.
```

If you don't want any optimization, remove any -xOn options.